# Why doesn't this html code scale well on the lower screens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

A little help please! Why doesn't this scale well on the lower screens? Everything else I have on the page scales well!

```
              <div class="form-group">
                <!-- Upper Label -->
                <label for="commission" id="label-eq-upper">Are these odds at an exchange? If so, they must
                  be
                  discounted with the commission.</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <!-- Inline Label -->
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="label-eq-inline">Write your commission or select from the dropdown menu if you're on a standard plan:</span>

                  <!-- Text Box -->
                  <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="commission" value="0%">

                  <!-- Dropdown -->
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a
                      standard plan<span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <li><a href="#">Matchbook</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Betfair</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Smarkets</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Betdaq</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Betsson</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
              </div><!-- /form-group -->
```

Is it because I can only have two elements in an input group?

Answer (score 0):

It is Because the **Text** *"Write your commission or select from the dropdown menu if you're on a standard plan:"* is too long .Most Probably.I guess you Might have to Change the text or Change the Design a Little Bit.

Just a Suggestion:
Try Adding it As Note At the Bottom As a Label May be ,

Comment: generally answers should have posted code with them

Comment: This hasn't solved my issue. Even making that text of one word length, the full row still isn't displayed correctly when I zoom into the page.